# Is it right to use the word "drain" for gas or smoke?

Tags: word-usage

Here are some sentences in a student composition:

> I'm thinking about the future design of the kitchens. Will it be better if we design a totally enclosed ventilation system, which includes poriferous ceramic tiles, ceiling materials, to drain and centralize the oil smoke though special pipes.

According to dictionary, the word "drain" is used for liquid. Is it right to use the word "drain" for gas or smoke?

Comment: Isn't gravity also involved with "draining"? You might consider the verb "vent".

Comment: "ceramic tiles *and* ceiling materials"

Comment: This questions sounds like it would be better suited to English Language and Usage, but words that would fit your sentence are 'exhaust' and vent'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Drain implies that something is flowing out due to gravity.

Smoke would typically be "vented"  meaning that it goes up by convection or "exhausted" if by mechanical force.

Comment: it's short, but there's not much to say. This answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

**Sure, the sentence is correct......! You may be asking how ? I will Explain bellow:**

**1. First let's see what is the meaning of the word "DRAIN"**

> ```
> cause the water or other liquid in (something) to run out, leaving it empty or dry.
>    "we drained the swimming pool"
> ```

**2. Still wondering that this word "DRAIN" will suit only with liquid substances right ? Here follow the explanation.**

> **In normal English the usage of the sentences like drain the gas tank of your car, drain the leaking cylinder are common because gas is
>   stored in its liquid form when it is stored inside a highly
>   pressurized container.**

So there is nothing wrong to say like:

```
    a. How to Drain a Water Heater ?

    b. drain gas tank 

    c. drain gas from boat tank 

    d. drain gas from snowblower....etc.
```

**3. Still confused ?
 you can google the word "Drain gas..............." You will get a thousands of sentences which uses this phrase.
Hope your doubt is solved and question is answered.**

Comment: @dennylv : Hope I helped someone today :)

Comment: I think you are confusing the American use of gas as a contraction for gasoline, what I would call petrol, for the gasious state of matter. Gasoline is a liquid, so "drain" is fine in all your examples, but I wouldn't use it for an actual gas.

Comment: @JosephRogers : 

[ GAS : An airlike fluid substance which expands freely to fill any space available, irrespective of its quantity. ] For petrol as it is a fluid you can use Drain with it also you can use drain with the "gas" you people are using. If you have a doubt just take google search engine and start the search with " How to drain gas.............." the rest of the suggestions you can see.

Comment: yes, for petrol you can use Drain, because it is a liquid. The results you will get for your suggested google search all refer to the American usage of gas as a synonym for petrol. I (a UK native speaker) would not use drain for a true gas. I would use vent if you're just opening a window, exhaust if it's being forced out from within (like the gas from a car's exhaust pipe) and extract if it's being sucked out (like an extractor fan in a kitchen).